# Is win-psycopg the best PostgresSQL adapter for Python to use on a Windows Machine?

Tags: django, windows, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm developing a Django web app on a Windows 10 x64 development machine using Python 3.7.2.  I would like to use PostgreSQL instead of the default sqlite database as I am planning to host this app on Heroku.

From what I've researched I need to use a PostgresSQL adapter for Python and the most popular one is Psycopg.  From what I can tell on the psycopg website, since I'm on a Windows machine, I need to use the **[win-psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/)** port, but it looks like win-psycopg only supports up to Python 3.5 and it hasn't been updated since July 2016.

I'm hesitant to go back to an older version of Python and use a port of an adapter that may not be actively updated anymore.

I am curious as to how other developers have setup Python and PostgreSQL on Windows.  Is there another adapter that would be better for Windows than Psycopg?

My other thought is to use MySQL instead, but that would mean I wouldn't be able to use Heroku.

Comment: What's wrong with [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/)?

Comment: Well the psycopg2 website has a seperate quick link  [Windows Download link](http://http://initd.org/psycopg/) that takes you to the win-psycopg download page.  So I've made the assumption that I need to use win-psycopg adapter instead of psycopg2 on my windows machine.  Also a recent [Django tutorial](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/optional_postgresql_installation/)  I was working through also directed Windows user to use win-psycopg and OS-X / Linux users to use pip install psycopg2.   I'll give psycopg2 a try.

Answer (score 0):

I installed psycopg2 via pip, created a test model in Django, migrated the model and was able to update the test table created in PostgreSQL via the Django admin.  So it looks like the psycopg2 adapter does work for Windows.  Not sure what the purpose of win-psycopg is.